# PowerShell - Add-Type with Join-Path

Tags: powershell, add-type

When I use the following code, the assembly and the included type are not loaded, and no error is raised.

```
Add-Type -Path (Join-Path $PSScriptRoot "..\..\SDK\Bin\Microsoft.Crm.Sdk.Proxy.dll");
```

Only when I save the path in a dedicated variable is it working:

```
$assemblyPath = (Join-Path $PSScriptRoot "..\..\SDK\Bin\Microsoft.Crm.Sdk.Proxy.dll")
Add-Type -Path $assemblyPath;
```

Any idea why the first approach is not working?

Comment: I would assume it is doing some kind of coercion for you in the second case.

Comment: What's your version of PowerShell?

Comment: Version is 5.1.14393.693

Comment: Have you tried running it with the `-Debug` and/or `-Verbose` switches?

Comment: Have you tried writing `Add-Type -Path $(Join-Path $PSScriptRoot "..\..\SDK\Bin\Microsoft.Crm.Sdk.Proxy.dll");` instead of `Add-Type -Path (Join-Path $PSScriptRoot "..\..\SDK\Bin\Microsoft.Crm.Sdk.Proxy.dll");` ? On my system (same PoSH version) this works just fine (even without using the additional `$`): `Add-Type -Path (Join-Path $PWD "..\Newtonsoft.Json.dll")`